# What to look for in automatic cat dry food feeders

Tags: cats, cat-food

I purchased an automatic cat feeder a few years ago, but it malfunctioned within a year. I ended up throwing it away.

Now I have to buy two of these things, and my budget is $40 each. I've found many alternatives at Amazon, but I'm not sure how to select the "correct" one and I don't want it to malfunction during the week I'll be traveling.

What do you suggest? I know I can't ask for recommendations, but is there a brand (or a specific machine) that's more reliable than the rest?

Comment: If you're buying from Amazon, your best bet is to just look at their reviews.

Comment: One trick I have found with Amazon purchases is to go to a brick-and-mortar store and find a similar item. That way you can examine it up-close and see the quality. Then you can buy from whichever store is cheaper, including shipping.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going away for a week, an automatic feeder is not a replacement for a friend or relative that you ask to check in on your cats.

No matter how reliable the brand and model, there is always a chance the one you received is faulty.